# vuetify divider vertical failed

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I want to add vuetify vertical divider from top to bottom card like this UI. [image: this UI] [In my codepen](https://codepen.io/handy29/pen/KKpjrxN?editable=true&editors=101), I don't know why the `v-divider` vertical is just only a little line you can see in the image below. [image]

My HTML code:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-layout row pt-4>
      <v-flex>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <v-layout row>
              <v-flex xs12 md2>
                <span class="subheading font-weight-bold">
                  Conversion
                </span>
                <v-divider vertical></v-divider>
              </v-flex>

              <v-flex xs12 md1>
                <span class="body-2 font-weight-bold">
                  Innerpack
                </span>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs12 md1>
                <span class="body-2 font-weight-bold">
                  Multipack
                </span>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs12 md1 pl-2>
                <span class="body-2 font-weight-bold">
                  Piece
                </span>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-divider></v-divider>
          <v-layout column>
            <v-layout row>
              <v-flex pt-3 pb-3 md2>
                <span class="body-2 pl-3">1 Carton</span>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex pt-3 pb-3 md1>
                <span class="body-1 pl-3 text-md-center">10</span>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex pt-3 pb-3 md1>
                <span class="body-1 pl-3 text-md-center">100</span>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex pt-3 pb-3 md1>
                <span class="body-1 pl-3 text-md-center">1000</span>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-layout row>
              <v-flex pt-3 pb-3 md2>
                <span class="body-2 pl-3">1 Innerpack</span>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex pt-3 pb-3 md1>
                <span class="body-1 pl-3 text-md-center">-</span>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex pt-3 pb-3 md1>
                <span class="body-1 pl-3 text-md-center">10</span>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex pt-3 pb-3 md1>
                <span class="body-1 pl-3 text-md-center">100</span>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-layout row>
              <v-flex pt-3 pb-3 md2>
                <span class="body-2 pl-3">1 Multipack</span>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex pt-3 pb-3 md1>
                <span class="body-1 pl-3 text-md-center">-</span>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex pt-3 pb-3 md1>
                <span class="body-1 pl-3 text-md-center">-</span>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex pt-3 pb-3 md1>
                <span class="body-1 pl-3 text-md-center">10</span>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-layout>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</div>
```

My JS (vue) code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      card_text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, brute iriure accusata ne mea. Eos suavitate referrentur ad, te duo agam libris qualisque, utroque quaestio accommodare no qui. Et percipit laboramus usu, no invidunt verterem nominati mel. Dolorem ancillae an mei, ut putant invenire splendide mel, ea nec propriae adipisci. Ignota salutandi accusamus in sed, et per malis fuisset, qui id ludus appareat.'
    }
  }
})
```

What's wrong in my code? What should I do?

Comment: Why not use a `v-table` ?

Comment: `v-card__title` add padding and makes a `v-divider` has less height

Comment: I dont understand what you mean